# Including Files Between Websites

Tags: php

I have several websites that function like one big CMS, with all sites based on includes hosted by one central website. I posted code from one of the satellite sites below to illustrate how I include files.

The problem is that I just activated PDO online, and it's causing all kinds of problems. There's apparently a conflict between PDO and my .htaccess files that I'm working on. At the same time, my includes aren't being included.

So I'd like to ask if there's an alternate method of including files between websites online, at least until I can fix the PDO/Apache problem(s). Thanks.

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path2 = str_replace('/', '', $path);

$Section  = current(explode('/', ltrim($path, '/'), 2));  // Main line 
$Sections = array('Introduction', 'Topics', 'World', 'Ecosymbols', 'Glossary', 'Reference',  'Links', 'About', 'Search');

if ( ! in_array($Section, $Sections)) 
{ 
 // die('Invalid section: ' . $Section); 
} 

switch (PHP_OS)
{
 case 'Linux':
 $BaseINC = '/home/geobear2/public_html';
 $BaseURL = 'http://www.geobop.org';
 break;

 case 'Darwin':
 // Just some code for my local includes...
 break;

 default:
 break;
}

include ($BaseINC."/2B/dbc.php");
```

Note: Here are the error messages I'm getting from the home page of one affected site. ACE.php is the name of the file that contains the code I posted above.

Warning: include(/home/geobear2/public_html/2B/dbc.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/symbolos/public_html/1A/ACE.php on line 67

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/geobear2/public_html/2B/dbc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/symbolos/public_html/1A/ACE.php on line 67

Warning: include(/home/geobear2/public_html/2B/inc/A1.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/symbolos/public_html/index.php on line 31

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/geobear2/public_html/2B/inc/A1.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/symbolos/public_html/index.php on line 31

Comment: PDO wouldn't affect this sort of stuff. PDO also has nothing to do with `.htaccess` and I can't imagine how you think they're interacting. You mention "all kinds of problems" without providing any useful details, and the code you've provided really doesn't tell us much at all...

Comment: I originally had an Internal Server Error (after my webhost enabled PDO). A support tech looked into it, and he said there was some sort of conflict between PDO and my .htaccess files, specifically the line  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off. When I commented that line out one of my .htaccess files, my site was partially restored...

Comment: Hmmm...My home page was restored as I was typing the comment above. However, no other pages display, as the link to my database connection file is still lost. I'll post the error messages in my original post, so they aren't so jumbled.

Comment: hey you asked that question already.. why not edit the other one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024576/pdo-fried-my-websites-any-tips

Comment: `magic_quotes_gpc` has nothing to do with PDO. Time to get a new host - if their support techs are that ignorant you're in for a world of hurt. The reason that setting is breaking your site is probably because the setting got **removed** in PHP 5.4 - if you're on a PHP 5.4 host, it has no clue what to do with that setting. See the red box in http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php.

Comment: @ Felix - That's a different question; I was trying to find out what's wrong and how to fix it. In the meantime, I need to figure out how to fix my includes while I'm waiting for a solution. That's what I asked about here - how to include files between sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're asking the wrong question... the way you "include" files in your application is a bit wrong and, i might say, "oldschool".

You should not include from other websites... if they are hosted on the same server you can use (if you have enough access, some servers will forbid you to do this), absolute paths for includes.

Also, your method will slow you down, and i doubt it worked in the first place...

See how include works here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
+++ cross reference require, require_once, include_once.

**Elegant solution:**
If you read the documentations properly and play around with it, granted your server has a newer version of php (5.3 atleast from what i remember, i may be wrong), you can start using namespaces.

Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

This is a wonderful way to have a common set of classes to use within your apps.
OOP knowledge is a must, for that i can't guide you much, there are hundreds of wonderful tutorials online.

Comment: OK, I'm looking at namespaces right now, but I can see it's going to take a while to figure out. If anyone can just show me how to use namespaces to include a file at mysite/2B/dbc.php, it would a huge help; I have over a dozen websites that are dead right now, and I don't even understand what the problem is. Not much time to learn OOP right now. ;)

Comment: Include works with files on the same server, you should and it will not work if you use it for website URLs! See how it works on php.net and re-think your strategy...

Comment: Wow, this is too bizarre - I've been wrestling with weird Apache problems for the past couple weeks, now PDO, and just now a support tech told me you can't include files between two CPanel accounts. I have a plan that lets me host several domain names on one server - but I can't include files between them...even though I've been doing it for the last ten years???

Comment: P.S. I've just been informed that CPanel was upgraded to prevent sharing files between sites. The upgrade went into effect a few years ago, but, for some reason, my account wasn't upgraded until I asked them to enable PDO.

Comment: Probably that is why it was working (it should never had in the first place) -- in cPanel you can add a website in 2 separate cPanel accounts and make them separate or you can use addon domains... having all files in the same directory structure, or just get a vps, you won't have cPanel but it's a lot better for configuring/etc

Comment: OR just use addon domains on one cPanel granted you're allowed to do that. doing an include('http://www....') will only include you the HTML output of that particular php file.